# In Python, print(lines) only working when code below is uncommented. Not inside conditional or after return

Tags: python, printing

I have a Python script that opens text files and then saves them as newly parsed files.

The code works: print(lines) on line 69 prints the parsed contents and the names of the files are also output if writing is successful.

However, if I remove or comment all of the code below line 70, print(lines) on 69 no longer works.

```
import os
import re

def parse_file(file_path):

  # open the file  
  with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    # read the contents
    contents = f.read()
  
  # split the contents into lines
  lines = contents.split('\n')

  # remove any line that includes the string "END OF TEXT FILE"
  lines = [line for line in lines if "END OF TEXT FILE" not in line]

  # add the part string
  lines[0] = "PART, " + lines[0]
  
  # filters out empty lines
  lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip()]
  
  # replace asterisks with an empty string
  lines = [line.replace("*", "") for line in lines]

  # replace asterisks with an empty string
  lines = [line.replace("•", "") for line in lines]

  # replace GB with an empty string
  lines = [re.sub(r'\sGB', '', line) for line in lines]

  # replace "MHz" with an empty string
  lines = [re.sub(r'\sMHz', '', line) for line in lines]

  # replace "mm" with an empty string
  lines = [re.sub(r'\smm', '', line) for line in lines]

  # replace W with an empty string
  lines = [re.sub(r'\sw', '', line) for line in lines]
 
  # combine the first line and second line if the second line does not start with "VRAM" or "Lighting"
  if len(lines) > 1 and not lines[1].startswith("VRAM") and not lines[1].startswith("Lighting"):
    lines[0] = lines[0] + " " + lines[1]

    lines.pop(1)
  
  # replace any ":" with ","
  lines = [line.replace(":", ",") for line in lines]

  # Trim the last entry in the list by extracting the digits after the dollar sign using a regular expression
  dollar_amount_regex = r'\$(\d+)'
  last_entry = lines[-1]
  dollar_amount_match = re.search(dollar_amount_regex, last_entry)

  # Extract the digits and construct a new string without the dollar sign
  dollar_amount_digits = dollar_amount_match.group(1)
  dollar_amount = dollar_amount_digits

  # Replace the original string with the dollar amount
  lines[-1] = dollar_amount

  # add "Price, " to the last line
  lines[-1] = "Price, " + lines[-1]

  # remove any extra whitespace from each line
  lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

  # CHECK OUTPUT
  print(lines)

# WRITING TO FILES
  
  # extract the first line from the list of lines
  file_name = lines[0].strip()

  # check if the lines contain the word "VRAM"
  if any("VRAM" in line for line in lines):
  # add "gpu-" to the front of the file name
    file_name = "GPU - " + file_name

  # check if the lines contain both "RAM Type" and "Frequency"
  if any("RAM Type" in line for line in lines) and any("Frequency" in line for line in lines):
  # add "ram-" to the front of the file name
    file_name = "RAM - " + file_name
 
  # create a new file path by joining the directory "D:\\Dev\\PAD\\pcbs-parsed-text" with the first line as the file name and .txt extension
  new_file_path = os.path.join("D:\\Dev\\PAD\\pcbs-parsed-text", file_name + ".txt")
  
  # save the lines to this file
  with open(new_file_path, 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
      f.write(line + '\n')
   
  return file_name

# search for files in the folder "D:\\Dev\\PAD\\pcbs-raw-text" with "output" in the title
raw_text_dir = "D:\\Dev\\PAD\\pcbs-raw-text"
files = [f for f in os.listdir(raw_text_dir) if "output" in f]

successes = []
errors = []

# parse each file
for file in files:
  file_path = os.path.join(raw_text_dir, file)
  try:
    file_name = parse_file(file_path)
    successes.append(file_name)
  except Exception as e:
    errors.append(file_name)
    print(f"Error parsing file {file_name}: {e}")

# check for success and print success or error, listing each file created
if errors:
  print(f"Error parsing files: {errors}")
else:
  print(f"Successfully parsed and saved files: {successes}")
```

I expected the print(lines) call to print the contents of the variable to the console but nothing happens.

To the best of my ability I've checked that print(lines) is not inside a conditional or a returned function.

I thought that Python otherwise executes top down, so I'm not sure about this one.

Still learning so it's probably something silly! Thanks.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a more minimal example?

Comment: Your program is fairly long and not line-numbered. I do not have patience to count up to 69.

Comment: If you delete all the code below line 70, then the function `parse_file` is never called, and the `print(lines)` inside of it never gets called.

Comment: Thank you for the responses!

I was trying to figure out how to line number my code, but you solved it before I could.